# Vagrant adding file to PATH in provisioning not working

Tags: bash, path, vagrant

I'm trying to provision a Vagrant machine to run liquibase. I'm able to install java, get liquibase through wget but I'm having trouble adding the liquibase executable to PATH. My current provisioning script looks like the following:

```sh
apt-get update
apt-get install -y unzip
apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre-headless
mkdir liquibase
cd liquibase
wget https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/v3.8.5/liquibase-3.8.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf liquibase-3.8.5.tar.gz
rm liquibase-3.8.5.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/liquibase
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

If I run `export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/liquibase` inside the machine it works. But during provision it doesn't work. I ssh into the machine and it's not in the PATH. I added the last two lines to see if I could make it persistent by adding it to .profile and .bashrc but it's still not working.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New PATH is not avaliable in your interacive shells.

Include your new PATH into the .bashrc file to have it avaliable when you login the machine.

```
echo 'export PATH="${PATH}:/home/vagrant/liquibase"' >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
source /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```